# Difference between “laden” and “loaded”

Tags: differences

In A. E. Housman's *With rue my heart is laden*:

> *WITH rue my heart is **laden**
>
>     For golden friends I had,
>
>   For many a rose-lipt maiden
>
>     And many a lightfoot lad.*

he refers to *laden* as loaded, burdened with regrets. But **laden** differs from **loaded** according to a pocketbook I have.

Can somebody help with the big difference?

Comment: I'm putting this in comments because it is not an answer to your question. I am not addressing *difference in meaning*, but rather *difference in etymology*.  Interestingly, laden is an adjective derived from the past participle of "lade", derived from OE, hladen, "to load".  Load derives from laeden, "to guide", and retained its meaning in "lodestone" (magnet, ie compass) and "lodestar" (guiding star, ie Northstar).  The meaning shifted to supplant "lade" c. 1300 BCE, see http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=load

Comment: offengehirn: (open mind) hladen == laden.  laeden == leiten. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While each has specific meanings that are not shared (eg "loaded" for "rich"), in their central meaning they are synonymous. (The *Oxford English Dictionary* uses each of the two as one of the words to define the other).

"Laden" tends to be more poetic, but it can still be used in ordinary speech.

Comment: do you mean it much like the difference between 'sans' and 'without'?

Comment: Not really: "sans" is very literary, and many people would not understand it. "Laden" tends to be literary, but it occurs in some common phrases (such as "heavily laden".

Comment: The difference is not just a matter of sounding more poetic, but of the connotations laden has (heavy, burdensome) that loaded does not.

Comment: People who wrote _Oxford English Dictionary_ like recursion. I am happy that programmers do not use infinite recursion to calculate something and mathematicians do not prove theorems this way (Theorem1 is true because Theorem2 is true, Theorem2 is true because Theorem1 is true).

Answer (score 4):

According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/laden) laden means

> loaded heavily with something: having
>   or carrying a large amount of
>   something.

It is something more than just being loaded. Furthermore, the term seems to be used more often in poetry than common conversations.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, looking at the synonyms of the words is most revealing.

On Merriam-Webster, [loaded](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/loaded) has synonyms like "brimming", "full" and "jam-packed". [Laden](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laden), on the other hand, has synonyms like "burden", "encumber", and "weight.

The connotation when you say "the tree was **loaded** with fruit" is positive: the tree is full of fruit, which means there's plenty to go around. When you say "the tree was **laden** with fruit", it's implying that the tree's branches are weighed down by their burden of fruit.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it more as volume (loaded) and mass (laden).  If the jar is filled with cookies, it is loaded, but hardly laden.  Whereas the 54' commercial hauling trailer carrying 25 tons of cookies is not overly laden, but is surely loaded.