# Does the Word "laden" Carry a Negative Connotation?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, meaning-in-context, connotation

So normally one could use the word **"laden"** to say,

The trees are laden with ripe fruit. ;
This sentence doesn't have any negative emotion linked to it.

But when used with other sentences, like,

The banks are laden with debt. ;

Then laden carries a negative connotation, dictionaries describe "laden" as being burdened with something, so does it always carry a negative connotation?

Just for the purpose of questioning its usage, what if one were to say,

He came in laden with presents. ;  One would find it to be a happy situation, so is it appropriate to use laden in ways like this?

Thanks for Your Help!

Comment: The usage does imply a burden of some sort, probably with a negative connotation in most cases: ***Laden***: 1) If someone or something is laden with a lot of heavy things, they are holding or carrying them.
[literary]
*I came home laden with cardboard boxes*. 2) If you describe a person or thing as laden with something, particularly something bad, you mean that they have a lot of it.
*We're so laden with guilt.* https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/laden

Comment: Depends on what the subject is laden/loaded with. "Laden" receives its connotation from the kind of burden itself.

Comment: Laden with gold coins = positive; laden with sacks of manure = negative (unless you are a farmer).

Comment: I would not use *laden with fruit* wrt trees. The trees have not been hung with fruit, they produced it themselves. *Laden* strongly implies an external object. See Note  14 [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11049-014-9227-y). Since you can put the prefix "un-" in front of *laden*, It's an adjectival and *are* is a copula. But it is an adjectival passive derived from an unaccusative verb.

Comment: Yes, 'laden' has a slight negative connotation as much as 'weighted' does (because the things one is weighted down or laden with are often heavy and therefore work to carry, a burden. But the more important connotation of 'laden' is that it is a bit old-fashioned, used mostly in child's fairy tales and purple prose trying to give an air of Middle Earth.

Comment: I recall that when I was a young man, if a girl gave me a glance that was laden with promise, I generally regarded that as a positive thing. I don't think it is quite ready for the dustbin of history or purple prose just yet. However I admit to being a bit bookish. That's OK on here, isn't it?

Comment: @PhilSweet - "trees laden with fruit" is such a common phrase that it is practically a cliché, which could be an objection, I suppose, but otherwise it is perfectly acceptable. Collins Dictionary says it's OK "Laden adjective If someone or something is laden with a lot of heavy things, they are holding or carrying them. ([literary) _The following summer the peach tree was laden with fruit._"

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Right, they are holding or carrying things. They are not primary producers of those things. That is excluded. A fishing boat harvesting fish is not laden with fish. A fish processing vessel (factory ship) can be. Laden implies the transfer of something - an act of lading.

Comment: @PhilSweet I don't see the difference between the fishing boat and the fish processing vessel, they both have had fish placed in them by some means for transportation. The connotation is that there are a lot of fish. I would say that a fishing boat with one fish in it is only comically referred to as laden with fish, but similarly with a fish processing vessel.

Comment: Is this answered by https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24279/difference-between-laden-and-loaded ?

Comment: Er, I actually strongly disagree with the selected answer there, so perhaps it's for the best that there's a new question. Yes, it sometimes does carry a negative connotation, but not always.

Comment: Yes, if "He came in laden with presents," **you would** find yourself happy, but **he would need to sit down** because he was burdened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Laden* is neutral. You can see the difference in meaning by looking at the same sentences but with a truly negative word such as *burdened*:

- The trees were burdened with fruit.

This difference is especially noticeable when the verb is paired with what would usually be a positive noun (like *money*):

- They are laden with money

  - (This frames it desirably)
- They are burdened by money

  - (This frames it negatively)

Usage-wise, as you note in the question, *laden* is often used in both positive and negative contexts (and plenty of neutral ones too). In [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), a basic collocation search for `laden with` shows “table” as the word that collocates most strongly with the expression, and the contexts for that are positive (“[table laden with comfort foods](https://www.southcoasttoday.com/article/19971112/news/311129922)”) or neutral (“table laden with books”). The next strongest collocate is “heavily”, which is used in contexts with all types of connotations such as the positive “[heavily laden with the fruit](http://shewhoeats.blogspot.com/2012/07/picking-summer-fruits-and-little-more.html)” or the negative “heavily laden with historical baggage”.

Going down the list of collocations, there are some groups that have negative connotations, some with positive connotations, and some that can go either way or are neutral. Either way, neither connotation is much more popular than the other.

Comment: Have a look at this, https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/laden    
    This is confusing me, it says laden is used for something bad in particular?

Comment: "If you describe a person or thing as laden with something, particularly something bad, you mean that they have a lot of it" is actually supporting this answer that context matters most. It's saying that laden is often used *when talking about* something bad (such as guilt), not that using laden *indicates* that it's bad. Laden means "weighed down by", and often people are weighed down by negative things, but a table "laden with food" is usually a good thing.

Comment: So "laden is used for something bad in particular" isn't an accurate rephrasing. More accurate would be "laden means weighed down, and is often used to when referring to something bad, such as guilt"

Answer (score 4):

Laden is neutral:

> 1745   T. Warton Five Pastoral Eclogues 20   Where..clust'ring nuts their laden branches bend.

(The quantity of nuts is obviously a good thing.)

> 1868   T. T. Lynch Rivulet (ed. 3) clxii. 198   Now mount the laden clouds, Now flames the darkening sky.

(The clouds are laden with rain - a storm is coming - which is not a good thing.)

> 1897   Daily News 13 Sept. 7/1   The laden trains start hence.

(The trains are being used efficiently - this is neutral - if they are laden with weapons it might be bad; if they are laden with supplies, it may be good. )

Comment: Words receive connotations from one another in context, don't they?

Comment: Instead of cut&pasting some cherry picked examples with no commentary, can you explain how in general these examples are exemplary of 'laden's neutrality?

Comment: @Mitch You may have missed the commentary - if you read them, you will see that it is within the examples

Comment: @Greybeard So those things in parentheses are things that -you- wrote? Then why are they in the quotes? That doesn't make sense. A quote is entirely from someone else. Also, what is the source of the quotes? Is it from a dictionary? Which one? Please try to follow standards of research otherwise it is very confusing.

Comment: In addition to formatting this properly, you should give some explanation as to why these examples are representative of the word's neutrality...I'm sure there are many more examples of it's somewhat negative connotation, but you should try to explain how your examples would outweigh them (I don't think you can but that's why I'm looking for additional explanation).

Comment: @Mitch *Then why are they in the quotes?* Mainly because of the strange way that formatting works on SE. I would say however that regardless of who wrote them, they make the point, and you seemed to have missed them when you commented. *you should give some explanation as to why these examples are representative of the word's neutrality.* Mitch... there is a positive, negative and a neutral use... if a word can be used like that, what is your conclusion. I don't spoonfeed - I expect some thought.

Comment: Thank you, your edits make things much clearer. Now that they are clearer, your explanations are sufficient to make your point. I disagree with the point but that is another matter entirely.